# Refresh PowerBI to reflect renamed table name from Data Source to the report

Tags: powerbi

We have multiple reports based on a database table, now we need to rename the table itself, how to refresh PowerBI reports to reflect the changed table name. Currently the new table name does not overwritting the old table that causes to re create all the reports again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made changes to table name in database, then you have to modify the "data source" in Power BI and choose the table you want. You can do it from Edit Queries> Data Source Settings

Then reload the data.